# Weird iOS crash with UIActivityViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have the following crash on iOS 6, image of stack trace is here:

[image: stack trace]

I have no idea what's going on but it is happening to a lot of users based on our crashlytics reports. We don't even use UIActivityViewController in our app, but we do have an Open In... function.

Comment: Premature deallocation sucks.  If you can't recreate it, then unfortunately, you're screwed.  All I can say is: breakpoints and zombies!

Comment: We have definitely tried that but have not been able to reproduce this locally. Seems to only be happening to app store users or we haven't found the clear path...